# Asp.net application for voice calls

Tags: asp.net, skype

I have a requirement for web application developed in asp.net which allows users to make voice calls among each other from the website.
I have looked at api of skype but it seems more inclined towards desktop application. IS there any api which supports for web application like gtalk etc. 
Which technology could be best used for developing such kind of applications? Any input, references would be helpful.

I did read that jabber is underlying technology for gtalk. Does jabber support voice calls, and would it be useful for my situation?

Answer (score 1):

If you can include Flash, it has API for that job, but for client side layer only... probably you can chose java/.net for server side.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution here is flash.  Gmail / Gtalk requires the user to download a plugin for it to work,  so technically it is a windows application being called from a webpage.

I recommend flash and asp.net for the backend, as said above.   Either that or if you are OK with deploying plugins,  you could go that route.  I wouldn't recommend it unless it is internal only.